# How can you use an timeout in a copy-item?

Tags: powershell

I want to copy about 600 files from windows server to a machine which is another located over WAN links about 200Mbps. I dont want to sature this link. As solution,  After each item copying to another windows server I want to wait about 15 seconds.

I have the following code:

```
[string]$sourceDirectory  = "C:\Temp\*"
[string]$destinationDirectory = "\\ipaddress\d$\Temp\"
Copy-item -Recurse -Verbose $sourceDirectory -Destination $destinationDirectory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you consider using robocopy with ipg? You can add bandwidth limitation while copying files. This would be better option without adding wait and also not impacting the link

```
[string]$sourceDirectory  = "C:\Temp"
[string]$destinationDirectory = "\\ipaddress\d$\Temp"

Robocopy /ipg:750 /E /z /r:3 /w:3 /tee /LOG+:c:\robolog.txt $sourceDirectory $destinationDirectory
```

& the formula to calculate ipg value:

[image]

```
Where
D is the calculated latency or inner packet gap
Bd is the desired bandwidth you would like to transfer at
Ba is the available bandwidth to you
```

for more details refer to this

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1073.robocopy-and-a-few-examples.aspx#Copy_with_bandwidth_limitation

http://blog.nold.ca/2015/07/limiting-bandwidth-using-robocopy.html